# AjaxToolkit - AjaxFileUpload Reset Queue List

Tags: asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I´m using AjaxFileUpload, and need to clear the queue list!
I search in google, and find the code below:

```
    function emptyMyAjaxFileUpload() {
    $(".ajax__fileupload_queueContainer").empty();
}
```

It works, but only visible to user, not really remove the files, from input i guess.

I need to remove files, like the remove button in each file in queue list, but in my site, i build another file list and hide the list from ajaxfileupload.

Resuming, I just need to clear queue list, from javascript or when i click in ´Select File´ button, the list go empty including only the new files.

Thanks in advance.
Sorry for the English.